# floor and ceil of X from a sorted array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, binary-search

Find floor and ceil of a number X from an array which is already sorted. e.g.

> a[] = {3, 7, 9, 10, 15}
>
> - if X=2, floor = N/A, ceil = 3
> - if X=3, floor = 3, ceil = 3
> - if X=4, floor = 3, ceil = 7
> - if X=16, floor = 15, ceil = N/A

I think most of us know about the solution i.e. we can find floor/ ceil by modified binary search. But problem with modified binary search is we need to take care of lot of boundary conditions. But i discovered that **same binary search algo does work but for floor we need to just write `if low > high return low`  and  for ceil `if low > high return high`**. And if floor return -1 then show N/A and if ceil return a value which is greater than array index than show N/A.

> **algo for floor:**

```
int floorSearch(int a[], int low, int high, int x)
{
    if(low > high){
        return low;
    }
    int mid = (low+high)/2;
    if(a[mid]>x){
        return floorSearch(a, low, mid-1, x);
    }
    else if(a[mid]<x){
        return floorSearch(a, mid+1, high, x);
    }
    else{
        return mid;
    }
}
```

> **and for ceil:**

```
int ceilSearch(int a[], int low, int high, int x)
{
    if(low > high){
        return high;
    }
    int mid = (low+high)/2;
    if(a[mid]>x){
        return ceilSearch(a, low, mid-1, x);
    }
    else if(a[mid]<x){
        return ceilSearch(a, mid+1, high, x);
    }
    else{
        return mid;
    }
}
```

it's very simple, isn't it? I have checked for many inputs and it does work but i have failed to proof the correctness of the algo. Can somebody give it a try to proof the correctness or you can also give a sample input for which this algo will fail. Thanks.

Comment: I am not really sure what you are asking, The definitions `floor` and `ceiling` I know, don't seem to match what you're asking about. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen edited, i have interchanged the def mistakenly. Thanks.

Comment: If you need to / are required to provide a proof of correctness for this algorithm: 1) you need to give it a go yourself, and 2) it is arguably off-topic for StackOverflow.  (If you have already given it a go, then show us what you've tried so that someone can give you a hint ...)

Comment: @StephenC i have tried already that i have mentioned in the question but i am not able to proof that to myself so i asked. and regarding the off topic issue i felt correctness algo can be asked here as i have seen it many times happening in stack overflow. sorry if my explanation does not soothe you.

Comment: @Trying - you will learn more by persisting and solving the problem yourself, than by reading someone elses solution.

Comment: Unlike the example that you gave, your code does not take care of the condition where floor or cieling does not exist.

Comment: @StephenC very true. But it took nearly 2 to 3 hours to solve the question and then i have been trying to proof the correctness for 2 hours but failed. So i thought of asking here.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @JimMischel - No this is not a request for codereview.  Proof of programs is a genuine programming activity, so this Question is on-topic in that respect.

Comment: @Trying Strange no-one has pointed it out, but your algorithm is wrong. Consider `a` = `[1,2,5,7,8]`. The floor value of 6 should be 5 here, but your algorithm would return 7.

Answer (score 1):

Hints on how to do the proof:

1. Proofs of correctness for these algorithms would follow the recursive structure of the algorithms; i.e. using proof by *structural induction* (look it up).
2. Look at a proof for standard binary search and figure out how it is constructed.
3. If there are bugs in your code, then you *should* fail to find a proof of correctness; see other comments and other answers!

Answer (score 1):

There is a traditional bug in the code. It uses `int mid = (low+high)/2;`. If the array is very large, it is possible for the addition to overflow to a negative result, making mid negative.

The bug can be fixed by using `int mid = (low+high)>>>1;`, as is done in the java.util.Arrays binarySearch methods. The `>>> 1` does, in effect, an unsigned divide by 2.

Comment: Answer is off topic. i know this but question is something else. Anyways thanks.

Comment: @Trying The question was whether the code is provably correct. It isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only modified the condition `if(low > high)`, note what that is equivalent to in normal binary search. Understanding the proof of binary search, determining correctness here should be nearly trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a test case that is going to break your code for ceilSearch.

a={3, 7, 9, 11, 13}, x=10.

I am listing low, high and mid in each recursive call:

(0, 4, 2) -> a[2]=9 < x

(3, 4, 3) -> a[3]=11 > x

(3, 2, 2) -> low > high, return low = 2.

The correct answer would be 3, not 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int[] floorAndCeil(int target, int[] arr) {
    int n = arr.length;       
    int[] ans = new int[2];     
    int l=0, r=n-1; 
    while(l<=r){                
            int mid = l+(r-l)/2;            
            if(arr[mid]>target){
                r=mid-1;
            }else if(arr[mid]<target){                               
                l = mid+1;
            }else{
                Arrays.fill(ans,arr[mid]);                        
                return ans;
            }
        }   
    ans[0] = (r==-1) ? -1:arr[r];   
    ans[1] = (l==n) ?  -1:arr[l];           
    return ans;
       
}
```

Comment: Please add explanations of your answer. Code-only answers are frowned upon on here, especially if the asker asks about a "proof" or "counterexample".